# How to sort html content (sort by author, sort by date etc) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, sorting

I recently started learning javascript so i dont know much yet which is why i needed a some help and guidance.. , I want to make a list of images with links on a page which can be sorted in the order I want after clicking on "sort by author" or "sort by date" for example.. I tried to make something :

```
   Javascript:

   var wspeare = document.getElementsByClassName("willimshakespeare");
   var jgreen = document.getElementsByClassName("johngreen");
   function Sortbyauthor(author) {
   this.author = author;
   if (author === "williamshakespeare") {
   for(i=0; i<wspeare.length; i++) {wspeare[i].style.display="block";}  
   for(i=0; i<jgreen.length; i++) {jgreen[i].style.display="none";}
   };      
   else if (author === "johngreen") {
   for(i=0; i<wspeare.length; i++) {wspeare[i].style.display="none";}   
   for(i=0; i<jgreen.length; i++) {jgreen[i].style.display="block";}
   };

  HTML:

  <li class="williamshakespeare">
  <a href="example.pdf"><img src="example"/></a>
  </li> 

  <li class="johngreen">
  <a href="example.pdf"><img src="example"/></a>
  </li>
```

So when i did something like Sortbyauthor("johngreen") it worked but when the number of authors gets to 8-9 with 10-12 books the amount of code gets very repetitive and long plus the alignment of images gets weird.

So if anyone could guide me on how to make a sorting program that would be very helpful. After getting some practice with how DOM works I am planning to learn jQuery so if jQuery is needed for things like sorting then ill wait till I learn that.

Sorry if i posted this in the wrong forum or something its my first post...

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be sorting, rather hiding and showing. To sort, you might consider creating objects with a property that references the related LI, plus properties with values that you want to sort on. Put the objects in an array. Sort the array using whichever value you want to use, then iterate over the array in an appropriate order to re–order the DOM elements.

Comment: @RobG , Thanks alot for your answer. Yes it is simply hiding and showing since I didnt know how to sort. Will follow your answer after I have more practice with working with dom.

Answer (score 0):

Click run code snippet, then click sort

```js
function doSort() {
    //grab all the lis
  var lis=document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  //make an array to place each author into
  var authors=[];
  //go through each li
  for (i=0;i<lis.length;i++) {
  //put the author in the array
  console.log(lis[i]);
  authors.push(lis[i].getAttribute('class'));
  }
  //sort
  authors.sort();
  //get the ul
  var ul=document.getElementById('authors');
  for (i=0;i<authors.length;i++) {
  
  console.log(authors[i]);
  //grab each author in the array
  li=document.getElementsByClassName(authors[i])[0];
  //add it back, sorted
  ul.appendChild(li);

  }
  }
```

```html
    <input type=button onclick=doSort(); value='click to sort' />
<ul id=authors>
 <li class="williamshakespeare">william shakespeare
  <a href="example.pdf"><img src="example"/></a>
  </li> 

  <li class="johngreen">john green
  <a href="example.pdf"><img src="example"/></a>
  </li>
  
  <li class="henrymiller">henry miller
  <a href="example.pdf"><img src="example"/></a>
  </li>
  
  <li class="stephenking">stephen king
  <a href="example.pdf"><img src="example"/></a>
  </li>
  <ul>
```